# How can I return only specific fields from a Objects List for serving a JSON response?

Tags: java, json, object, playframework

I tried with @JsonIgnoreProperties and @JsonIgnore but no lucky..

This is my main:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result index() {
    //I read the JSON Post request
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    Item[] items = Json.fromJson(json, Item[].class);

    //I convert all the dueTime from string to jodatime DateTime, using the formatter with ISO 8601
    items = addJodaTime(items);

    //I sort the items by dueTime in jodatime DateTime format
    Arrays.sort(items);

    return ok(Json.toJson(items));
}
```

and where I put my ignore stuff, which is not working..

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"dueTimeNew"})
public static class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String duetime;
    public String jointime;

    @JsonIgnore
    public DateTime dueTimeNew;

    public DateTime getDueTime() {
        return dueTimeNew;
    }
```

any idea how to return only id and name?

Comment: What is the json you get at the end?

Comment: Check that your annotations are coming from the same package as the json processor you're using. Don't mix `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` for instance.

Comment: @Salem, actually the json is correctly sorted by one field, and returned with a list of objects and relative fields. And I would like to return only a subset in a elegant way..

Comment: @mike actually I have these (sorry don't know how format the code in the comments yet!): imports import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
//import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.util.*;

Comment: I'd also add the annotation to the getter as the behavior you're looking for varies with version and we're not seeing the whole picture.

Comment: @mike, what/where is the Getter? You mean where I load my Json in my "main"? Above the instructions request().body().asJson(); and FromJson?

Comment: @Micky it's not clear from the snippet if there is a getter, or if it's generated by an add-in... the suggestion is _if_ there is a getter. Sorry for the confusion. For this to be a good question you should include the _complete_ object you're trying to JSON marshal (Customer?) and the project's dependencies (pom.xml or something equivalent).

Comment: @Micky Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add @JsonIgnore to every field you need to ignore. If you don't do this, Jackson will add everything that is public or has a getter (a `get???????????` method).

In your case, you have a lot of fields, and only `dueTimeNew` is being ignored... Also note that, because you have a `getDueTime` method that uses `dueTimeNow`, this will be added also. If the method was named `getDueTimeNow` it would be ignored probably.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a seperate class for response with just the fields u want to return ?